# Why python uses predictable hashes for numbers?

Tags: python, security, hash

The [Python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) says:

> By default, the `__hash__()` values of **str and bytes** objects are “salted” with an unpredictable random value. Although they remain constant within an individual Python process, they are not predictable between repeated invocations of Python.
> This is intended to provide protection against a denial-of-service caused by carefully chosen inputs that exploit the worst case performance of a dict insertion, `O(n2)` complexity.

But [the algorithm used for computing hash()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#hashing-of-numeric-types) of numbers is deterministic. (It only uses salt for str and bytes). Why an attacker can not use integers to run DoS by the same reason?

Comment: You're missing the part that says "See http://ocert.org/advisories/ocert-2011-003.html for details." in the paragraph you're quoting. Which has a link that you want to click on.

Comment: Just guessing, the number of cases where an attacker could pick arbitrary integers for a dictionary is much lower.

Comment: Lots of discussion on the bug tracker here: https://bugs.python.org/issue13703. A key consideration was that "it's not possible to directly create a dict with integer keys via JSON or XML-RPC"

Comment: It's a matter of the size of the attack surface. Colliding `int`s could be used but the situation where that might occur is exceedingly unlikely compared to where `str` or `bytes` are used - namely in automated processes that ingest text or binary data. "Solving" the issue for `int` would cause a near-universal and significant performance hit while providing negligible value.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Dear mike, I had fully read the ocert link and it's totally quiet about "python" implementation details! But the python issue said by slothrop was truly useful

Comment: @slothrop I think that would be a good answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Python bug tracker ([Issue 13703](https://bugs.python.org/issue13703)) captures a lot of discussion that led to this choice.

Particularly significant factors were:

1. JSON and XML-RPC messages are always interpreted with strings, not ints, as dict keys. (See relevant messages from the thread for [JSON](https://bugs.python.org/issue13703#msg151063) and [XML-RPC](https://bugs.python.org/issue13703#msg151064).) So in the most plausible security threat context (requests fired at a service on the web), int hashing was seen as unlikely to cause an issue. There wasn't 100% consensus on this: [this message has a dissenting view](https://bugs.python.org/issue13703#msg152855).
2. "Using a more elaborate hash algorithm would slow down uses of
   numbers as dictionary keys and also be difficult to implement for
   non-integer types such as float, longs and complex numbers." (quote from [this message](https://bugs.python.org/issue13703#msg152787))

Essentially, the view that won out was that the security benefits of the change won out over the performance impact for strings and `bytes` objects, but not for numeric types.